# Store long string externally but needs be translated to exe with the scripts

Tags: python

I have a function in my program that will send an email to a user. I have a template for the email that will use the python placeholders which will be replaced with the users information such as their name. The program needs to be converted/translated to .exe when being deployed and the templates are very large strings and I assumed it is not best practice to just set them to a string within the script.

I have tried creating a separate script that contains all of the templates and them importing this into the main script which works but I'm not sure if there is a more elegant way of doing this such as created a permanent external file that will be converted into the .exe . I have also tried using a plain text file but I assumed this would not get translated into the .exe with the rest of the script.

```
email = """<h1>Welcome</h1>
<p>This is an example email that contains your temporary password: %s</p>
<p>The end of my really short example email :P :) </p>"""
```

Comment: I think trying to store strings that will be formatted in a separate text file is too complex. You will need to create a parser, and are really just making more work for yourself by taking the strings outside python. Personally I see no reason the template can't be in your main script (or at least some script), since editors (mine is PyCharm) can simply collapse the entire string and eliminate the need to even look at it unless it is being altered.

Comment: I am also using PyCharm, if that’s the best way to go, I will do that, wasn’t sure if there was an obvious better practise

Comment: Perhaps if you are rendering HTML (which it looks like you are), you should look into the [flask framework](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/tutorial/templates/) and if that's sort of what you are looking for, the tutorial starts [here](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/tutorial/layout/). This will allow you to stay inside python, but dynamically create HTML pages. The templates are stored externally, but the parser has already been made for you! You just have to learn the syntax :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution to this problem was to store the long strings in a separate python script and import them into my main script.